# np.where to search whole column

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe in this format

```
Date       D1         
12/8/2017  12/7/2017  
12/7/2017  12/2/2017  
12/6/2017  12/1/2017  
12/5/2017  
12/4/2017  

df['Exist'] = np.where(df['Date'] == df['D1'], 1, 0)
```

The above code does not work as it only looks at the same row, how do I make it such that it will search the whole D1 to produce:

```
Date       D1         Exist
12/8/2017  12/7/2017  0
12/7/2017  12/2/2017  1
12/6/2017  12/1/2017  0
12/5/2017             0
12/4/2017             0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both columns are of the same dtype:

```
df['Exist'] = df['Date'].isin(df['D1']).astype(np.int8)
```